# Repeated phrases such as 'four times it stopped on the very threshold of the gate, four times the armour clanged'

Tags: expressions, literary-device

I was wondering if there is a phrase or word for this language technique. Virgil, and other classical poets use it quite a lot. For example

> 'three times she lifted herself on her elbow. Three times she fell back down...'

Answer (score 2):

It's a device called **[repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device))**.

> Repetition is the simple repeating of a word, within a sentence or a poetical line, with no particular placement of the words, in order to secure emphasis. This is such a common literary device that it is almost never even noted as a figure of speech. It also has connotations to listing for effect and is used commonly by famous poets such as Philip Larkin.

Your example uses the kind **anaphora**:

> Anaphora is the repetition of a word or phrase at the beginning of every clause. It comes from the Greek phrase, "Carrying up or Back".
>   "We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills, we shall never surrender." (Winston Churchill)